# Problemas con xrange Python

Tags: python

Hola de nuevo a todos,

resulta que instalé una librería para llamar a unas funciones, pero esas funciones usan la función xrange y por algún motivo Python no la reconoce...

El error es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 85, in <module>
    b = metrikz.pbvif(reference_images[5], reference_images[2]) # PBVIF
  File "/home/lucia/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymetrikz-
0.4-py3.5.egg/metrikz.py", line 265, in pbvif
    zipped = map(lambda x: __get_num_den_level(ref, dist, x), xrange(1, 5))
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined
```

¿Tiene que ver con que use Python3.x y no Python2.x?

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Desde ya gracias.

Lucía

Comment: Efectivamente, `xrange()` existe en python 2.x pero no en python 3. Puede ser sustituida por `range()`. Echando un vistazo al proyecto y a la librería en cuestión parece ser antigua (2011) e implementada en Python 2. Si puedes, usala con python 2.7, de no ser posible dado que está bajo GPL y no es muy extensa podría adaptarse a Python 3 manualmente y adaptando las dependencias apropiadamente para Python 3 (por lo pronto requiere PIL que no existe para python 3 pero si su fork Pillow, con el resto SciPy y Numpy no debería haber problemas en principio). Esto requiere de tiempo y conocimientos.

Comment: cuando lo hago con python2 prueba.py el error que sale es el siguiente:               File "prueba.py", line 17
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file prueba.py on line 17, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details,  en la línea 17 justamente lo que tengo es import metrikz que es la librería en cuestión

Comment: qué es PIL y fork Pillow? :O

Comment: No me gustan esos errores porque son imposibles de reproducir en muchos casos XD. Intenta añadir estas dos lineas al inicio de tu script prueba.py: `#!/usr/bin/env python` y `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`como el propio enlace al PEP recomienda. [`PIL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library)(Python Imaging Library) es una librería para abrir, procesar/manipular y guardar multitud de formatos de imágen , originalmente existe para Python 2, `Pillow` es una adaptación de `PIL` para Python 3 (no una almohada com parece... XD). Posiblemente ya la tengas instalada si usas SciPy

Comment: por qué esas dos líneas cambiarían algo si son comentarios?

Comment: Son comentarios y no lo son, si las **dos primeras lineas** de un módulo son de ese tipo el intérprete las usa para establecer la codificación (en este caso UTF-8). En Python 2 la codificación del archivo es ASCII por defecto a no ser que se lo especifiquemos de esta forma. La primera línea se usa en sitemas UNIX para especificar el intérprete que debe usarse para ejecutar el módulo. [Aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations) tienes la documentación sobre el tema de la codificación.

Comment: No se si solucionará tu problema, como dije al principio son problemas simples pero que dan la lata mucho porque son difíciles de reproducir, yo importo el módulo en Python 2.7 sin problemas. Hay veces que esto se debe al editor usado, a copiar texto codificado de una forma en un archivo con otra codificación y mil cosas más. ¿Puedes importar el módulo en el intérprete interactivo? o ¿si creas un archivo nuevo con solo el import (escrito a mano, sin copiar y pegar) funciona?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un hack pequeño:

```
try:
    xrange = xrange
except NameError:
    xrange = range
```

Si xrange es presente, nunca va a pasarse. En contrario, si no hay xrange en tú Python instalación, vas tener un alias por range ordinario.